# Fixing cam not detected (/dev/video0 missing) error in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, webcam

My integrated cam was working fine as long as I was using ubuntu 16.04 provided by Dell. Once I upgraded the cam stopped working with error in "Cam not detected". Computer is not able to detect the cam. 
I installed packages libuvc-dev, libv4l-0 etc based on various google solutions. and finally also compiled the uvc driver and install it using following link

https://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/How_to_Obtain,_Build_and_Install_V4L-DVB_Device_Drivers

Did git and compiled the code and followed innstructions upto "sudo make install" and rebooted machine.

But still no driver install. Am I missing any step here? 
If you have solved this issue can you please share what step am I missing? How can I make my cam work again?

after installation folder structure

ashutosh@stratbeansAsh:/lib/modules/4.15.0-70-generic/kernel/drivers/media$ ls

cec       dvb-frontends  mc        pci       rc      usb
common    firewire       media.ko  platform  spi     v4l2-core
dvb-core  i2c            mmc       radio     tuners

UPDATE:
I am able locate uvcvideo.ko .... how can I make ubuntu use it?

ashutosh@stratbeansAsh:/lib/modules/4.15.0-70-generic/kernel/drivers/media/usb/uvc$ ls

uvcvideo.ko

Comment: Are there any errors when you do: `sudo modprobe uvcvideo` ?

Comment: I did not get any  error